# quasi- linear equation(curve of discontinuous solution )

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Help me please to solve this equation:
$u_{t}+c\left [ u(1-u) \right ]_{x}=0$  in [a,b]

$c$ is constant.
Find smooth boundary and initial conditions when the solution is discontinuous .

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On which domain do you consider your equation? Is there any correspondance between $q$ and $u$? Is $c$ constant?

Comment: @martini Oh, thanks. It's no q just u, in[a,b], and indeed c is constant

Comment: Does the expanded form of your PDE is $u_t+cu_x-2cuu_x=0$ ?

Comment: @doraemonpaul yes, it's the expand form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u_t+c[u(1-u)]_x=0$

$u_t+c[u-u^2]_x=0$

$u_t+c(u_x-2uu_x)=0$

$u_t+c(1-2u)u_x=0$

This belongs to a PDE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fpde/fpde2203.pdf

So the general solution is $x=ct(1-2u)+C(u)$